# Do I need to update my Google Drive sign in?

Tags: ios, google-authentication

I have an iOS app that logs in to a Google Drive using the method outlined in the Google Quickstart page - [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift)

I have seen the message from Google about modernizing OAuth interactions

> Authorisation requests in embedded browsers will be blocked on April 20 2017

I'm not using an embedded browser but I'm still getting this warning message.  Can anyone confirm if this is a general message displayed for everyone, or does the fact that you're seeing the message indicate that it is relevant?

Do I need to change my access, and what happens if I keep trying to use this legacy method - does it simply fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that iOS Quickstart is outdated as far as the login part goes and that you'll need to use the new  Google Sign-In procedure.

Google Sign-In for iOS:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start

This page had some useful info when learning about the process:
https://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/

A few other things I found useful for me:

1) .hasAuthInKeychain can be used to determine if a "silent" login should work

2) .currentUser of nil means you need to login through code, but user doesn't necessarily need to see login screen (if keychain auth exists)

3) After getting a .currentUser, you can use the old API code (at least for me) by assigning the authorizer as follows:

```
service.authorizer = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer;
```

Edit:

I've decided to switch to AppAuth instead of "Sign In".  I'm using the following cocoapods which use the latest (I think, v3) Google API, along with AppAuth

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive'
pod 'GTMAppAuth'
```